How can I improve the presentation of a buffet?
I've just started as a chef de cuisine of a hotel in the north region of Brazil. Mostly of my experiences comes from classic french cuisine, I've worked in multiple Michelin starred restaurants and hotels in Brazil, Switzerland and France, but I'm having a hard time trying to improve the presentation of food platters that are served in the buffet, it's my first experience in this kind of kitchen.
I'm learning the hard way that presenting large amounts of food is a whole different universe than that of plated dishes. I've heard that the chef before me used to carve fruits and vegetables to present the food preparations, a lot of banana leaves as well, but I find that this type of presentation doesn't fit the branding of the hotel.
Does anyone have any tips or references on how could I improve these types of skills?

Welcome to the site! This question isn't really a good fit, for one thing it's very broad as there are many possible approaches, it's also open to opinion as to what makes good presentation. I suggest you browse the web for pictures of hotel buffets for ideas, keeping in mind efficiency in setup as well as re-use.
